# Playlist in C# (axWindowsMediaPlayer)

Tags: c#, winforms, media-player

I have this FolderBrowseDialog

```
  FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        fbd.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
        fbd.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;

        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string folder = fbd.SelectedPath;
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(folder))
                this.listView1.Items.Add(f);  
        }
```

I want to add all the songs in ListView1 to a axwindowsmediaplayer playlist. How would I achieve this?

Comment: This doesn't solve your main issue, but you may want to interrogate the files in the directory in order to make sure that they are supported by the media player.

Comment: Are you still having issues?

Answer (score 4):

`ListViewItemCollection` doesn't implement the generic `ICollection<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` interfaces, so the compiler can't guess the type from looking at the `Items` collection. Hence why you have to explicitly tell the `foreach` loop that it's iterating over a collection of type `ListViewItem` instead of using `var`.

Thus the following code works:

```
var myPlayList = 
      axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("MyPlayList");

foreach (ListViewItem media in listView1.Items)
{
      var mediaItem = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia(media.Text);
      myPlayList.appendItem(mediaItem);
}

axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentPlaylist = myPlayList;
```

When you iterate through the `listView1.Items` in a `foreach` loop using an implicitly-typed variable (`var`) then `media` is treated like an `object`. So when you call `ToString()`, you are in fact calling it on a `ListViewItem`. Which like many other .NET classes - `ListViewItem` overrides the `System.Object.ToString()` method. Which looks like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return "ListViewItem: {" + this.Text + "}";
}
```

Hence, what happens when you use `foreach (var media in listView1.Items)` and call `axWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia(media.ToString())` you are in fact calling `axWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia("ListViewItem: { C:\\Users\\...\\file.mp3 }";)` which obviously doesn't work.

However, you can use `var` successfully by casting each item you are iterating over into a `ListViewItem` as in the following code.

```
        foreach (var media in listView1.Items)
        {
            var fileLocation = (ListViewItem)media; // This step is critical!
            var mediaItem = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia(fileLocation.Text);
            myPlayList.appendItem(mediaItem);
        }
```

But I think this defeats much of the point of using `var` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
var pathToFiles = "Path to where the media files are stored";

var mediaPlayer = new AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer();
var myPlaylist = mediaPlayer.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("myPlaylist");

foreach (ListViewItem fileName in listView1.Items) {
  var media = mediaPlayer.newMedia(Path.Combine(pathToFiles, fileName.Text);
  myPlaylist.appendItem(media);
}

mediaPlayer.currentPlaylist = myPlaylist;
```

Comment: Yes... Well it was "something like this should work". Though I changed it a bit now but still: Something like this should work. If it doesn't work then find out why. Do some research.